# Codeigniter: The default value of a text input field if data is not returned from the controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a text input which is populated by values from the database passed from the controller. This is how I have done it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupname" name="groupname" disabled value="<?php foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo $r->group_name;
};?>"/> <br>`
```

This code should be executed once a search button is clicked and its working well. My problem is, every time I load the view,this input field is loaded meaning this code executed and since I have not searched anything, it is giving me an error. How can I set the default value of the input box to be null/empty by default or if no value is returned from the controller.

Am a newbie. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to check $result is blank or not using if(!empty($result)) before loop

Comment: A value is returned if i search. That part is working fine. all I want set the default value of the input box if nothing is searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether search performed or not by checking your array

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupname" name="groupname" disabled value="<?php if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){ foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo $r->group_name;
} };?>"/> <br>`
```

**Explanation**

I use `if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){` condition in this i have checked that if your search happens that means there `$result` will be set and there must be something in `$result`.
But if you simply refresh page then there is no value in `$result` so it will not process `foreach` loop.

Comment: search happened. I'm just displaying the outcome in an input box. In this case I want to set the default value

Comment: You are the best... Its working!! Please explain it for me to make me understand better. Am still new in PHP (codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupname" name="groupname" disabled value="
<?php 
   if(count($result)>0){ 
       foreach ($result as $r) {
          echo $r->group_name;
       }
   }?>"/> <br>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: result. I found the best way of doing this: checking if the search happened and if a value was returned. If yes, continue to execute the foreach(). Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You should set empty array with `$result = array();` before your call to the function, or you can do it in the `foreach()`, like this `foreach((array)$result as $r)`... see more here: [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I don't understand it your way. A value is returned if i search. That part is working fine. all I want set the default value of the input box if nothing is searched.

Comment: Your set a default value like this. if you put `$result=array();` you set a default value. An empty array. Or when you set `foreach((array)$result as $r)` you set `$result` as an array if is not set..